# varnish multiple backend not working

Tags: varnish

I have 2 backends in my Varnish configuration: one dynamic server and one static server.

The configuration for the backends is as follows:

```
backend default { 
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8484";
  .probe = {
   .interval = 5s;
   .timeout = 1s;
   .window = 5;
   .threshold = 3;
  }
}
backend default_1 { 
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8181";
  .probe = {
   .interval = 5s;
   .timeout = 1s;
   .window = 5;
   .threshold = 3;
  }
}
```

When i am trying to restart the Varnish server it fails to restart.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Anything in varnish logs?

Comment: i checked the log and the issues i only adding the backend not using any where that's why showing error message

Comment: So you're saying you are not using all of the backends that you have defined in your vcl? Then there's your answer. Comment out the ones you don't use anywhere in your vcl, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 4):

If you declare a backend, you need to use it : it is how Varnish does.

Anyway, you have several solutions to your issue. The prefered one is maybe to still declare unused backend in your VCL, run Varnish, while you will convert error into warnings by adding the parameter `-p vcc_err_unref=off`

Comment: I have also use this to verify sytanx Varnishd -C -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl